# A Time Minimization Optimization Problem with Many Constraints maybe could be solvable by functional analysis.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis

[![My problem is here are so many limitations that I don't know how to solve it. I guess it maybe could be solved by functional analysis
Here is what I get：
The parameterized equations for the trajectory of the plane departing from point A are given as: s1=(x1(t), y1(t)).
The parameterized equations for the trajectory of the plane departing from point B are given as: s2=(x2(t), y2(t)).

min  $$t=\frac{\int_{0}^{4500} \sqrt{1+\frac{y1'^2}{x1'^2}}  \,dx }{10}$$

1. $|x1'y1''-x1''y1'|\leqq \frac{100}{3}$
2. $|x2'y2''-x2''y2'|\leqq \frac{100}{3}$
3. $\sqrt{x1^2+y1^2}\geqq500$
4. $\sqrt{x2^2+y2^2}\geqq500$
5. $\frac{|x1y2-x2y1|}{\sqrt{(y1-y2)^2+(x1-x2)^2}}\leqq500$
6. $\sqrt{x1'^2+y1'^2}=10$
7. $\sqrt{x2'^2+y2^2}=10$

And here is the entire problem.
Two unmanned aircraft, A and B, are positioned on the plane at points located on the extension lines of the diameters of a circular obstacle with a radius of 500 m. Point A is 1 km away from the center of the circle, while point B is 3.5 km away from the center. Both unmanned aircraft depart simultaneously from points A and B, flying towards each other's destination at a constant speed of 10 m/s. During their flight, the unmanned aircraft must avoid the circular obstacle and must not meet each other (meaning that the line connecting the two aircraft must remain in an intersecting state with respect to the circular obstacle). The minimum turning radius for each unmanned aircraft is 30 m. The objective is to minimize the time it takes for the first aircraft to reach its destination. Provide the flight trajectories for both unmanned aircraft.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7UAk.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7UAk.png)